# Bypass setup wizard in fusion auth to create application

Tags: authentication, fusionauth, setup-wizard

I am using Fusion Auth as an auth backend for my project.

After starting up the container as shown here(https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/docker), if we open the URL(Ex: http://localhost:9011) we need to create an admin user and then we will be able to create **Application**, **API Key**, **Lambda**.

[image: fusionauth setup wizard]

As my project doesn't involve UI interaction, I wanted to create **Application** without involving UI interaction(i.e., setup-wizard).

I was unable to find an API that relates to setup-wizard.

As I saw `Since this is your own private instance of FusionAuth, you need to create a new administrator account that you will use to log in to the FusionAuth web interface.` in setup-wizard I thought this is required only for UI, So I tried to create **Application** using this(https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/applications#create-an-application) API, but it is returning a 401(Unauthorized).

Can someone help me to either create an application without authentication or bypass setup-wizard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FusionAuth Kickstart does exactly what you need. It will allow you to pre-define the configuration that you require in a JSON file and then the system will bootstrap itself automatically.

The base use case it to provision an API key which would allow you to programmatically configure the rest of the system by using APIs after an API key has been created.

```
{
  "apiKeys": [{
    "key": "a super secret API key that nobody knows"
  }]
}
```

You also have the option of building your entire configuration in the Kickstart definition. There are a bunch of examples and walk throughs on the [Kickstart installation guide](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/kickstart).

Good luck!

Comment: Is it necessary that I have to create an admin user to by-pass setup-wizard?
Because I have created an API key using Kickstart. But then I opened  http://localhost:9011 still, I can see setup wizard, I created user logged in and that API-key I created was not present. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Until at least one users exists in FusionAuth - you will be prompted with the setup wizard. That is to say, until a user has been created that can log into FusionAuth we have no choice but to prompt you to create a user. If you want to create the user using an API with the API key you created in Kickstart that is fine. In that case, kickstart the system, call the User Create API and register that user for FusionAuth and then you will not see the Setup Wizard.